# How do I list IP addresses a system is connecting to from its memory dump or OS image (obtained from FTK Imager)?

Tags: network, forensics, ioc

I'm looking for a tool that will enumerate the IP addresses that a system is connecting to. This is mainly for forensic purposes, to gather IOCs. I know we can run a netstat on windows, but would like something that is comprehensive and reports all processes (hidden, system, etc.)

Comment: Netstat is not processed-based, it does not matter if a process is hidden. It can list all connections.

Comment: What about connections going through a proxy or a NAT, will it list the destination IP or my internal proxy server IP?

Comment: It does not matter where they do through as longs as they exist.

Comment: To answer this question, we need more information. What exactly is the situation? Are you working on a RAM-dump? A live system? If so, what operating system? As it stands now, your question is too broad. Please [edit] your question to add all the relevant information.

Comment: It will list the addresses that your machine has a connection to, e.g. a proxy. The forwarding of traffic happens in the proxy, not your PC (that would make a proxy pointless).
Ultimately if you're in doubt it's comparably cheap to format your machine and start over.

Comment: I will be working with a memory dump or an image of the OS

Answer (score 1):

In Linux you can use `netstat -ptan` and if you don't have netstat you can use `ss -neopa`
and if you are connected to a server trough a proxy you will not see the ip address of that server is connected to which process.

Answer (score 0):

For windows use this [TCPView](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview), this is a great tool for looking for exactly what you are looking for.  If you want to look at the actual content of the traffic, check out [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org) which allows for you to view the packets.

**Happy hunting!**